# How do I control when Emacs makes backup files?

Tags: emacs, backup

I can't seems to find information on when does Emacs makes backups. It generally works great, but today I've lost some part of a file because of Magit infamous revert shortcut and after looking at my backups directory don't find any of the files I've worked on today. Everything seems to be there for previous days tough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs [backs up](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html#Backup) when you visit files, and [auto-saves](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save.html) periodically when you edit - the manual (linked above) details things to change to make that process more aggressive. Unfortunately, 
pressing `v` in the status buffer for magit does not count as either visiting or editing the file, but note that [a patch was commited](https://github.com/philjackson/magit/commit/f8e429e8defeba85922e94da668bbd4ebc531782) to magit to ask for confirmation before reverting.

Comment: Good answer, that also what I thought, even tough it doesn't really address my issue. For some reason Emacs backup doesn't work at all today, I've tried restarting it, still nothing. I'll edit my question to be more precise. I just learned about the `magit-revert-item-confirm` option after that happened.

Comment: Finally I've accepted your answer. The problem with backups/auto-saves on my system seems much more complex than what I thought at first and I'm just too lazy to update the question accordingly! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking Emacs will save every single keystroke in backup files, by default named `#foo#` if your file is named `foo`.  For more details, have a look at [this AutoSave entry](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave) on the Emacs Wiki.

And/or search here for `[emacs] backup` or `[emacs] autosave` as this has been discussed before.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs do not make backup of a file when a VCS take care of it It believe that the git/cvs/svn will take care of the backup mechanism.

Note also that magit 0.8 have been release with confirmation before reverting:
you need to add

```
(setq magit-revert-item-confirm t)
```

in your .emacs to be protected.

Comment: It's not really an answer to the current question, but the default value of magit-revert-item-confirm Just have been changed in the magit's git main repos.